# Apache2 Ubuntu (Debian style VHost conf) - how to I change the default server?

Tags: debian, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

Output of `apachectl -D DUMP_VHOSTS` yields the following:

```
root@ip-x-x-x-x:~# apachectl -D DUMP_VHOSTS
VirtualHost configuration:
x.x.x.x:80        is a NameVirtualHost
     default server dev.x.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.x.com.conf:1)
```

...followed by

```
port 80 namevhost dev.x.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.easysigns.com.au.conf:1)
port 80 namevhost prod.x.com...
```

And so on.

How do I change the `default server` which is at the top of the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default server is based on the lexicographical order of the vhost.conf files.

Steps to resolve the issue:

- Navigate to /etc/apache2/sites-available/
- Disable prod.x.com.conf `a2dissite prod.x.com.conf`
- Rename prod.x.com.conf to 000prod.x.com.conf `mv prox.x.com.conf 000prod.x.com.conf`
- Enable 000prod.x.com.conf `a2ensite 000prod.x.com.conf`
- Restart Apache `service apache2 reload`

The site prod.x.com is now the default site.